# ford E150 wiper modular

Tags: ford, van, econoline, e150

I research the problem with my wiper that it would not stop working. I disconnected the fuse for now because it was draining my battery. Although the wiper stoppped when I turned off the engine. I bought wiper moudulator. Except I can't find where to replace it.
-- Not by fuse box under the dash drivers side. Not in the engine connection box. Nothing on the passenger side. I looked under the wiper motor area, but did not take a deeper look because I did not want to take any other electrical stuff off.  Some say behind glovebox. There is no glove box except the airbag area. Help please!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Wiper motors usually have a built-in switch that keeps the power on to the motor until the wipers are in the parked position.  If this switch becomes faulty, one fault mode is the wipers keep running permanently.

When you say that you have bought a wiper modulator, I presume you mean wiper module or wiper motor.

The motor is located underneath the panel where the wiper arms attach as in this photo -

[image]

[This video shows how to replace it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxW3THOUm3s)

Comment: Yes wiper module needs to be replaced can't find where it is.